# Array format problem and passing array to functions

Tags: c++, arrays

My question is about arrays for this program.

So far I have this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_SCORES = 3;
const int NUM_STUDENTS = 5;

double getClassAverage(const double[], int);
double getStudentAverage(const double[], int);
double getHighest(const double[], int);

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 15;
    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int count = 0;
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("p6.dat");

    while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> numbers[count])
        count++;

    inputFile.close();

    cout << "The numbers are: ";
    for (count = 0; count < ARRAY_SIZE; count++)
        cout << numbers[count] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}   

//Function for averaging columns for Test Average.
getClassAverage(const double , int size)
    for (int col = 0; col < NUM_SCORES; col++)
    {
         double total, average;
         total = 0;

         for (int row = 0; row < NUM_STUDENTS; row++)
             total += scores[row][col];

         average = total / NUM_STUDENTS;

         cout << "Score average for test "
              << (row + 1) << " is " << average << endl;
    }

//Function for averaging rows for Student Average.  
getStudentAverage(const double , int size)
    for (int row = 0; row < NUM_STUDENTS; row++)
    {
         double total, average;
         total = 0;

         for (int col = 0; col < NUM_SCORES; col++)
             total += scores[row][col];

         average = total / NUM_SCORES;

         cout << "Score average for student "
              << (row + 1) << " is " << average << endl;
    }

//Function for finding highest test score in array.
getHighest(const double , int size)
    for (int col = 0; col < NUM_SCORES; col++)
    {
          int count;
          int highest;
          highest = numbers[0];

          for (int row = 0; row < NUM_STUDENTS; row++)
          {
              if (numbers[coount] > highest)
                  highest = numbers[count];
          }

             cout << "The highest score is " << highest << endl;
    }
```

When I run the program it displays it like I have it saved in the file, but I want to take it from a single line to a 2 dimensional matrix (3 x 5).

Contents of p6.dat:

> 75 78 86 91 72 99 87 70 60 50 40 20 64 79 95

```
 75 78 86
 91 72 99
 87 70 60 
 50 40 20
 64 79 95
```

Would I get rid of `const int ARRAY_SIZE` and replace it with two variable names set to 3 and 5 respectively for rows and columns? The way I would like the matrix formatted sets it up so that the first row is the 1st students 3 test scores, repeat for student #2, and so on. The columns represent tests 1-3. Then I have some questions on passing the array to some functions for calculations.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simplest to keep using a 1-D array (or even better, use a `vector`, then it can be resized).

If you want to output your 15 items in a 3x5 table, just modify your output loop to print a newline after every 3 items.

If a function needs to know how long each row is, then just pass that in as another variable.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about?                                                                (row = 0; row < NUM_STUDENTS; row++) then for the inside use (col = 0; col < NUM_SCORES; col++) for the conditions of a nested for loop

Comment: I meant using a single loop, but that would work also